# Restating the problem for proving the definition of infinite dimensional vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra

This question is taken from Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right:

> Prove that $V$ is infinite-dimensional if and only if there is a sequence $v_1,v_2,...$ of vectors in $V$ such that $v_1,v_2,...,v_m$ is linearly independent for every positive integer $m$.

The definitions of finite and infinite dimensional vector space are given in the book:

> **1. Finite-dimensional vector space:** A vector space is called *finite-dimensional* if some list of vectors in it spans the space.

> **2. Infinite-dimensional vector space:** A vector space is called *infinite-dimensional* if it is not finite-dimensional.

From this, I would love to restate the question as the following form, though I am not sure if my understanding is correct. Also note that the concept of basis has not yet been covered in the book prior to this exercise, but the restatement of the question might help me understand why the general definition of an infinite-dimensional vector space is often denoted as *"a vector space that has a basis containing infinitely many vectors"*. The restatement is as follows:

$$\text{Prove that for all finite sequences } v_1,v_2,...,v_n \in V \text{ does not span } V \iff \text{ there exists a sequence } v_1,v_2,...,v_m \in V \text{ that is linearly independent for every positive integer } m \text{.}$$

Comment: A better wording:   No finite sequence in $V$ spans $V$ $\iff \text{ there exists a sequence } v_1,v_2,... \in V \text{ such that}\,\, v_1,v_2,...,v_m \,\text {is linearly independent for every positive integer } m$

Comment: Lol that would be even better. Thanks!